# How to change a dependency property of a user control by pressing a button that belongs to the user control?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

Let's say we have a user control with a simple dependency property named Percentage of type double. Value of Percentage is being shown in a textblock. Also there is a button that must change the Percentage property while being pressed. What is the best way to do this?

I expected the code to look like this:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp3.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             x:Name="MyControl">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="{Binding ElementName=MyControl,
                                  Path=Percentage,
                                  StringFormat=N2}" />
        <Button Width="100"
                Height="50">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="MyControl"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Percentage">
                            <DoubleAnimation From="0"
                                             To="100"
                                             Duration="0:0:1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to do this?

Attach a `Click` event handler to the `Button` and implement this one to change the property of the control or, if you are using the Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) design pattern, bind the `Command` property of the `Button` to an `ICommand` property of the view model that sets a `double` property that is bound to the `Percentage` property of the control.

Either way, you should it *programmatically* in C# (or whatever programming language you are using) and not in the XAML markup.